# EJS Interpolation: Variable not defined when used inside script tag

Tags: node.js, ejs

My variable can be used while outside `script` tag, but not from the inside.

#### Route.ts

```
router.get('/myRoute/:myId', async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction)=> {
const userData = {
  name: 'blabla',
  age: 22
}

res.status(200).render('myPage', { userData });
});
```

#### myPage.ejs

```
<html>
<head>
<% console.log(userData) %> // Log the content without a problem

<script>
  console.log(userData) // THROWS ERROR: userData not defined
</script>
</head>
```

How may I use this interpolatio from the inside of `script` tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that would be because outside the script using `<% %>` it's rendered `server side` (in node), while inside the script it's rendered `client side` (in the browser)

and if you check the `script` in the browser you will notice that no variable `userData` has been defined

you want declare the variable in the script tag and parse it

```
<script>
 //if it's a json object
 const userData = JSON.parse('<%- JSON.stringify(userData) %>')
 //if it's a normal variable
 const userData1 = '<%- userData %>'
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. Silly question: Would be possible to do this showing only the variable name instead of its value? (Under Inspect Element). Probably not, but...

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro that wouldn't be possible because you're writing the variable as a string on the page

Answer (score 0):

This method also works

```
<script>
 var userData = <%- JSON.stringify(userData) %>;
</script>
```

Comment: Hi!  The code won't compile if I use `<%` inside `<script>`  :\

Comment: Hi, is `<%-` not `<%`   @PlayHardGoPro